Missing static Main function while building docker image
I'm having a problem creating a docker image of my .NET program. My program builds fine locally but when I try to create a docker image, I get an error that I am missing a static Main method. I took out all the actual code.

Error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/Middleware.csproj] #15 5.937  #15 5.937 Build FAILED. #15 5.937
#15 5.937 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

I'm so lost because I clearly have a static Main method but I'm still getting the error when building the docker container. Am I missing something?
This is my Program.cs with the code redacted
namespace Middleware
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            VaultClientConfiguration clientConfig = new VaultClientConfiguration
            {
            };            

            // Code removed

            await webHostTask;
        }
        
        private static async Task RunWebHostHealthCheck(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Code removed
        }
    }
}


Do you have any other code files in your project? This is most likely because you're accidently using Top Level Statements.

What version of .NET are you targeting?

Can Main return an async Task? I've only ever returned an async void (or void or int). I imagine an async Task<int> would work too.

@Flydog57, yes Main when async must return Task. returning void complains of Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point. What is the current version of C# that you're using? async Main is available starting in C# 7.1

@gunr2171 Yes; outside of dependencies, I have like 15 files. I'm using .net8.0
Flydog57 It builds fine locally so I assume it does. But if it breaks a rule, I'm more than willing to change. I'm using 8.0 so I read that it was fine.
